# Perform a command adding an extension to list of files

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows executable `munge.exe` which takes an input `.dat` file and produces a file with the `-o` parameter for the output filename. I want to append (not replace) an `.out` extension to the output, so I call it like this for `foo.dat` and `bar.dat`:

```
munge foo.dat -o foo.dat.out
munge bar.dat -o bar.dat.out
```

I just got a large directory of various files, among them many `.dat` files. Many of them have spaces in their names. It's so much work to munge them manually. I thought PowerShell could help. As a newbie, I did a few searches and came up with this, making liberal use of aliases:

```
dir *.dat | %{munge $_.name -o $_.name+".out"}
```

Needless to say, it didn't work. I tried to find out where I went wrong, so I just tried to echo the commands to see what was going on. (The wonderful `-whatif` as you might expect doesn't help me, because of course it doesn't work with script blocks. Of course. Wonderful)

```
dir *.dat | %{echo munge $_.name -o $_.name+".out"}
```

No go; it thinks that `-o` is a parameter of `echo`. So let's quote the thing!

```
dir *.dat | %{echo "munge $_.name -o $_.name+.out"}
```

Oops I'm getting `.name` and `+` in the interpolation. Maybe if I use the `${…}` format and leave out the `+` since it's interpolation.

```
dir *.dat | %{echo "munge ${_.name} -o ${_.name}+.out"}
```

Um … no. That gives me `munge -o .out`.

(sigh) Looks like I'll have to learn all the Powershell tricks just to do basic things (as I had to do with Bash). Nothing is simple I guess.

What is the way I'm supposed to do it?

Comment: your first example is almost right, you just need `(...)` to let powershell know you want the concatenation to be resolved first. `dir *.dat | %{munge $_.name -o ($_.name + ".out") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant documentation in this case is [**about Operator Precendence**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.2).

You need to use the [Grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) so that the string concatenation between `$_.Name` and `.out` is resolved **first** in the expression:

```
Get-ChildItem *.dat | ForEach-Object {
    munge $_.name -o ($_.name + ".out")
}
```

As for the second example, where you attempt to [`echo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.2) the result, in this case, you need the [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) so that the string interpolation is resolved first :)

```
Get-ChildItem *.dat | ForEach-Object {
    echo "munge $($_.name) -o $($_.name + ".out")"
}
```

Lastly, regarding [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-whatif), `echo` (`Write-Output`) **is not a cmdlet that [supports `ShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2#supportsshouldprocess), hence no `-WhatIf` switch is available for it**.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The parentheses did the trick. Regarding `-WhatIf`, I wasn't trying to use it with `Write-Output`. Rather I was using `Write-Output` _because_ `-WhatIf` didn't work with the command block. (I was hoping it would give me something like evaluating an SQL query plan so I would know what to expect before running the command "live").

Comment: @GarretWilson I see, makes sense now, I misread it then. `-WhatIf` is only available to Pwsh functions and cmdlets

Comment: Regarding the `echo` example you gave, I can actually use nested quotes like that?  So somehow parentheses take precedence so much that it overrides the quoting? I've never heard of that before. Usually in languages the outer quoted string would be parsed as a token before the expressions within it are evaluated. It would seem that PowerShell is somehow interpolating and evaluating at the same time it is parsing the entire outer string? Wow.

Comment: @GarretWilson that's the beauty about precedence in powershell (the doc I linked explains it really well). The subexpression is evaluated first, then gets interpolated in the string